# Adobe After Effects - Why is my position marker not set to a frame?

Tags: after-effects, framerate

In after effects, one of my compesitions is comprised soley of static images, vectors, solids, and other non-movie footage. One such static image layer lasts from frame 0 for 100 frames.

Another user has edited this file while i was away, and amongst these edits they changed the framerate for this compesition and managed to change the static image's lifetime in a funky way. It was still 100 frames long, and started at frame 0 on the compesition, but it some odd things had happened to it at the layer instance level.

The problem is that the static image has been given start time offset, and when I try and rectify this using the layer preview of said solid image, I can't set the cursor, in-point or out-point to a solid frame. When if scrub through the timeline I find myself always in-between frame markers; the cursor simply will not sit dead on frame 0 and will either snap to (aproximately) frame 0.125 or frame -0.625. The snap seems to be offset +0.125 frames and jumps in 0.5 frame ammounts.

The lifetime of the image as seen in the layer preview:
[image: Image lifetime]

A close up of the timeline showing that the cursor is in-between frames:
[image: An oddly ofset frame cursor]

I suspect it was due to the fps change, but that actually needs to stay as it is, so I need to rectify this issue without changing that. How can i fix this odd frame snap and snap offset?

This may ultimiately seem like a non-issue for many, but for us it's a breaking problem, as it's causing funky things to happen with one of our plugins, so any help rectifying this would be apprecated.

It's probably worth noting that my After Effects (along with my animation and movie editing knowledge in general) is very beginner. I'm at home in Photoshop, but I've been required to use After effects for my current project, so the fix may be simple, but i must be using a wrong keyword somewhere as I'm finding nothing remotely close to this when i search.

Comment: This thread could share some insights.
https://community.adobe.com/t5/after-effects-discussions/ae-playhead-not-snapping-on-the-next-keyframe/td-p/11184419

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to go into the layer source to set the in-point of a layer. In the comp timeline select the layer, put the playhead at the frame you want and hit <kbd>alt / opt</kbd><kbd>[</kbd>. For the outpoint it's <kbd>alt / opt</kbd><kbd>]</kbd>.

Should you wish to learn more have a look at [the docs here](https://helpx.adobe.com/in/after-effects/using/selecting-arranging-layers.html#trim_extend_or_slip_edit_a_layer).